# Function not being defined even though ive saved it

Tags: python

I have a fully working programme that I wish to run. It executes on my friend's laptop, but not mine, (I've saved it to my documents folder) the following is the program:

```
def DigitCount(n):
    #how many decimal digits in integer 'n'
    if n<0:
        n=-n
    digitCount=1
    powerOfTen=10
    while powerOfTen<=n:
        digitCount+=1
        powerOfTen*=10
    return digitCount
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
>>> DigitCount(100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    DigitCount(100)
NameError: name 'DigitCount' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you show us the script that is calling it ?

Comment: When you start the python terminal, it doesn't automatically find every python file on your computer (What if you wrote two functions with the same name in different files?)  Instead, you must use `import` statements to tell the interpreter where to look.  If your code is saved in a file name `digitcount.py`, then you would use the statement `import digitcount` to import your code.  You would then access it like `digitcount.DigitCount(100)`

Comment: you're running from the console. You have to import the file containing your function first!

Comment: sorry what would you like to see? Both the programme and the error message are displayed above :)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thanks for your help! where exactly do i place the import statements, im a complete newbie to programming

Comment: @AidanCronin As a rule, before anything else at the top of the file/interactive session.  There might be exceptions, but I've honestly never seen any.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thanks very much , i found a second digit count saved in a different folder , but the import did the job, much appreciated!

Comment: @AidanCronin: definitely.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Would there be any other reason as to why the function isnt being recognised because I got rid of the duplicate that i had also saved for digitcount, see we arent supposed to have to import the function in class

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Would there be any other reason as to why the function isnt being recognised because I got rid of the duplicate that i had also saved for digitcount, see we arent supposed to have to import the function in class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait, are you saying you do the following from the command line?

```
$ python DigitCount.py
$ python
>>> DigitCount(100)
```

That won't work.  You have to do this:

```
$ python
>>> import DigitCount
>>> DigitCount.DigitCount(100)
```

Comment: Yes that did work for me , but we arent supposed to have to import the function in class, i deleted my replicate digitcount and now only have one but python still doesnt recognise the function?
I still get the error that it isnt defined?

Comment: @AidanCronin -- I don't know what "aren't supposed" means here. Functions are local to the file they are defined in, unless they are explicitly imported to another.